# JS copy one object to another

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```
myModel = 
    {  
           Id: '',
           Category :'',
           Values: {
             userName: '',
             pasword: '',
             address: ''
           }
        }
```

newModel may look like this:

```
{
Version : "12.1",
Values : {
 "somenewProp" : "with a value"
}
```

I want myModel to look like this at the end of this merge:

```
myModel = 
        {  
               Id: '',
               Category :'',
               Version : "12.1",
               Values: {
                 userName: '',
                 pasword: '',
                 address: '',
                 "somenewProp" : "with a value"
               }
            }
```

I have the exact same object format with values that I want to merge, I am doing the following:

```
this.myModel = Object.assign(this.myModel, ...newModel);
```

MyModel doesnt change, I need to be able to merge new properties and assign properties from the newModel into myModel

Comment: Don't use spread syntax on non-iterable values?

Comment: Just use `Object.assign(myModel, newModel);`

Comment: Notice that `Object.assign` won't *merge* anything, and not on the nested `.values` anyway, but just overwrite properties.

Comment: so how do I do it ? I need to basically merge items from newModel into myModel, but keep any extras in myModel untouched. I need to be able to merge nested objects

Comment: Please show us what `newModel` actually looks like and what "extras" there are.

Comment: I updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` is not recursive, nothing in the ECMAScript standard library offers recursive merging of two objects. You need to either :

- Write your own recursive merge function
- Use a third party library (eg. [merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge), [lodash.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge), etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Assume;

```js
myModel = {  
  Id: '',
  Category :'',
  Values: {
    userName: '',
    pasword: '',
    address: ''
  }
}

subModel =  {
  Version : "12.1",
  Values : {
    "somenewProp" : "with a value"
  }
}
```

Then `newModel = {...myModel, Version: subModel.Version, Values: {...subModel.Values, ...myModel.Values}}` will give you the result you want. Although, the readability of the code would be poor.